# For the word 'operate', why does OpenNLP's POSTagger return type as 'NN'?

Tags: java, opennlp

I parsed two sentences with openNLP program

1. > The machines in Lab1 are unable to operate.

It returns *operate* has type `NN`

2. > It is an uneasy time to learn java in lab1 because the machines are unable to operate

It returns *operate* has type `VB`

Why? How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you reference/mention the model files that you are/were using for this experiment?

Comment: The (legacy) EN POS tagging model, found on Sourceforge for version 1.5.0+, was used.